# ansible-test doesn't use PYTHONPATH environment variable during execution. How to override

Tags: python, ansible

When running `ansible-test units -vvv` I noticed that the PYTHONPATH var in the output doesn't have what I've setup in the system. (note, running the same command via pytest works fine)

```
PATH=/tmp/ansible-test-js1exv63-injector:/tmp/python-brdg1v39-ansible:/root/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/root/.local/bin/
PYTEST_PLUGINS=ansible_pytest_collections
PYTHONPATH=/tmp/ansible-test-nei1j811:/root/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible_test/_util/target/pytest/plugins
```

when I run `echo $PYTHONPATH` from the same terminal I get:

```
/src/ansible_collections:
```

Using python 3.9 / ansible==7.3.0 / ansible-core==2.14.3

How can I override this?

Comment: I know of at least one operating system where ansible is packaged wrapped in a shell script that overrides PYTHONPATH. Wouldn't hurt to look at the executable that's providing `ansible`; if instead of being the direct Python code it's a shell wrapper, take a look at what that wrapper does.

Comment: And ansible _always_ adds PYTHONPATH entries for modules it copied over ssh; that's how it's expected and intended to work.

Comment: so ansible-playbook works fine resolving modules.

Whereas ansible-test doesn't, strangely I tried also using the `--local` flag.

Comment: Also I noticed that it doesn't have a shell wrapper, just python although very bare bones, just validates and calls `cli_main(args)`

Comment: I also found this though, just not sure where to move from there:
`Injecting "/tmp/python-y30zi963-ansible/python" as a execv wrapper for the "/usr/local/bin/python" interpreter.`